# Snowflake: Regex for text between the last slash and dot?

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I have the string:

```
test_stage/parquet_location/9f7d37fd-7039-4454-94ef-2b0cd6c3206a_b1df97ad-54dc-4fc9-a099-1fb9cd6530be_custom_1696963985.parquet
```

How do I write a regex that will match the text delimited by `_` that's between the last `/` and `.parquet`. So above text will match:

`9f7d37fd-7039-4454-94ef-2b0cd6c3206a`

`b1df97ad-54dc-4fc9-a099-1fb9cd6530be`

`custom`

`1696963985`

I tried below expression but no luck:
`(?<=/)[^/_]+(_[^/_]+)*.parquet`

To clarify, I am using Snowflake:

`SELECT regexp_substr_all('/abc_ds/ef/gh_xy_z.parquet', '<regex_exp>') AS matches;`

which would return all matches

Comment: Not sure which regex flavor is supported, but you might opt for matching `[a-z0-9-]+(?=[^\s/]*\.parquet$)` https://regex101.com/r/ucHS51/1 This will also match when there is no forward slash. Or you could assert `_` or `/` before the match `(?<=[_/])[^/_\s]+(?=[^\s/]*\.parquet$)` https://regex101.com/r/xxF5Nu/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried with Snowflake but getting error "Invalid regular expression: '...', no argument for repetition operator: ?"

Comment: Ah, I did a quick check here, but I think lookarounds are not supported https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to avoid regex, personally, but your string seems to be something fairly simple to pull apart using `SPLIT_PART` and `SPLIT`.  Have you looked into using something like this?

```
with x as (
    select 'test_stage/parquet_location/9f7d37fd-7039-4454-94ef-2b0cd6c3206a_b1df97ad-54dc-4fc9-a099-1fb9cd6530be_custom_1696963985.parquet' as str
    )

select split(split_part(split_part(str,'/',-1),'.parquet',1),'_') as arr,
       array_contains('9f7d37fd-7039-4454-94ef-2b0cd6c3206a'::variant,arr) as match
from x;
```

Looking at the nesting from inside out, it first finds the everything after the last `/`, then pulls off the `.parquet`, and the splits the remaining string into an array separated by the `_`.  Once you have the array, you could do whatever you need in comparing to values.  In the code above, I'm just using an `array_contains` on a specific string to see if it exists in the array.  You could also flatten the array, pivot, whatever is needed basically.

I know this doesn't explicitly answer your question on regex, so if you don't find it useful, I can remove the answer, but it is efficient code in Snowflake.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!